# jquery ajax inside another ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is some javascript/jquery code:

```
$('#button').click(function()
{
     $.get("php/doit.php?id=<? echo $r['id']; ?>", function(html)
     {
         alert(html);

         // $.get("php/doit.php?id=<? echo $r['id']; ?>", function(html)
         // {
               // alert('omg!');
         // }

     });
 });
```

The second ajax request should be called when the first is completed, right?  The above code works great, but as soon as I uncomment the second request, the whole javascript block fails - I dont even get the 'alert' anymore.  Even if you put an alert just to test the .click it does not work.

Is there something that I should be clearing after ajax requests? Why exactly can I NOT make 2 requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `);` for the second `.get`. It's just a syntax error.

Comment: AHHH!! I cannot believe it took me this long to see that!  I guess sometimes all you need is another pair of eyes. :D  Thanks.